# Question about the existence of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x)g(x)=15$ what can I say about the existence of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{g(x)} $?

My attemp: if I consider $f(x)=e^{x-1}-1$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{e^{x-1\over 15}-1}$ the limit is null but can be infinity?

Comment: If $g(x)$ is bounded as $x\to1$ then $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)g(x)=0\ne15$ by the squeeze theorem. One can conclude that $\lim_{x\to1}g(x)=\pm\infty$ and hence the given limit is always zero.

Comment: Hint $\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)g(x)}$ (assuming $f,g \neq 0$ in the nbd. of $x=1$ etc.) and both limits of numerator and denominator exist so $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{0}{15}=0.$